# Change the color of the Intel NUC 11 Power LED from a running process

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, intel-nuc

On an Intel NUC (model Intel NUC11TNHi7), Ubuntu 20 LTS is installed. I want to be able to use a process (such as a bash script, python, library, etc.) to control the button LED such as from systemd or crontab. Although I operate the NUC headless, there have been times when the operating system has failed to boot properly and the only method to debug the issue was to plug in a display to see an error. Although fixing the boot issue shouldn't be a reoccurring task, I would still like to change the LED to something that is unique ( maybe amber or even red) to quickly diagnose that a process is running or in this case the OS was properly booted up. Is doing this task simple? Although it largely focuses on Windows, I can see references to this [page](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000026641/intel-nuc/intel-nuc-kits.html), but nothing that I have been able to come across has been as straight forward as I hoped.

Comment: The page you linked to states that "the NUC Blog also has information for this: [Linux Kernel Driver for NUC LED Control](https://nucblog.net/2017/05/linux-kernel-driver-for-nuc-led-control/)" and this link leads to a step-by-step instruction. Have you tried to follow it? Ultimately you govern the LED with commands like `echo 'ring,80,blink_medium,green' | sudo tee /proc/acpi/nuc_led > /dev/null`. Is there any problem or error? Or do you need help with setting up some logic (i.e. translating "that a process is running" or "if the OS was properly booted up" to such commands)?

Comment: I must of overlooked this link on the page somehow. I don't have an Intel NUC at this moment, but I'll take a stab it in the next coming week.

Comment: Looking and after first attempts, nothing seem to work. Not sure if the repo is outdated since it has not been maintained since 2017